# Allow only one Digit in Jquery

Tags: jquery, regex

Is there any Regular Expression to allow only one numeric in a textbox. ie, The user can type only one numeric (0 to 9) in that textbox.

Comment: duplicates : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995183/how-to-allow-only-numeric-0-9-in-html-inputbox-using-jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995183/how-to-allow-only-numeric-0-9-in-html-inputbox-using-jquery)

Comment: This would work: `^\d{1}$` or `^[0-9]{1}$`, but only to validate input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why regex when you have `maxlength` Attribute and  [input type=number](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.number.html)

```
maxlength="1"
```

Comment: How about valid numeric value ??

Comment: Note: `type=number` is HTML5 only.

Comment: @techfoobar now-a-days html5 has become a part so they can use overcome by using [`html5shiv`](https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) right.  Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @PraveenJeganathan - Yes, HTML5 wouldn't be a problem most of the time. Just pointing out still.

Answer (score 0):

simple overwrite keydown event and allow/disalow keys

```
        //delete, tab, enter, escape, backspace
        var allowedKeys = [8,9,13,27,46];
        jQuery("input[class=num]")
            .attr('maxlength', 1)
            .keydown(function(event) {

            // Allow: , delete, tab, escape, enter and .
            if ( jQuery.inArray(event.keyCode,allowedKeys) !== -1
                || (event.keyCode == 65 && event.ctrlKey === true)
                || (event.keyCode >= 35 && event.keyCode <= 39)) {
                return;
            }
            else {
                if (    event.shiftKey
                        || (event.keyCode < 48
                        || event.keyCode > 57)
                    && (
                        event.keyCode < 96
                        || event.keyCode > 105
                    )) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like that

```
var regex = /^[0-9]{1,1}$/;

function checkInput(){
    if(regex.test($('input').val()))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```